# Ajax Routing Calling Controller Name Twice

Tags: ajax, model-view-controller

I am trying to do a simple call to my controller via ajax.  The RouteConfig has not been changed and set to the default values.  When I make ajax call, the Url that is requested in the "Network" debugging tools is:

```
'http://localhost:59275/Leaderboard/Leaderboard/GetPosition'
```

This is causing a 404 because the Controller, Leaderboard, is being added into the Url twice.  The correct url should be

```
'http://localhost:59275/Leaderboard/GetPosition'
```

My ajax call is as follows:

```
  $.ajax({                
            url: 'Leaderboard/GetPosition',
            type: "GET",
            dataType: 'xml',
            success: function (data) {
                $('#results').html(data);;
            }
        });
```

and my controller is as follows:

```
public class LeaderboardController : Controller
    {
        [Webmethod]
         public static DataTable GetPosition()
         {
             // do stuff
         }


    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the root URL of the page that request the ajax is "Leaderboard" then the url on the ajax call should only "GetPosition"

Or you can use "/Leaderboard/GetPosition" with "/" in front

Comment: I know this is 5 years old, but could you explain more? 
Why do we need "/" in front? In my case, when I debug my application it will add the controller to it and the url will be `product/product/listofproducts`, but without debugging it will be correct and be like this `product/listofproducts`. 

Your solution works but I didn't find a resource that explains why. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Url.Action` helper for generating correct url.

Change this:

```
 url: 'Leaderboard/GetPosition'
```

to this:

```
 url: '@Url.Action("GetPosition","Leaderboard")'
```

Comment: This did fix my issue with the duplicate controller in the url. Thanks