# angular route template not found 404

Tags: angularjs, spring

Hi when i run the spring angular app it is showing `GET http://localhost:8080/cyclone/admin/admin/cycle 404 (Not Found)` . i don't have any idea where the second admin came from on the url.

access url `<a href="#/cycle">Cycle</a>` and the html page under `WEB-INF/views/admin/cycle.html`

**Angular root setup**

```
 App.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/cycle', {
            templateUrl: 'admin/cycle.html',
            controller: 'CycleController'
        });
    }]);
```

**My Spring controller**

```
  @Controller
    @RequestMapping(value = "/admin")
    public class AdminController {
            @RequestMapping("/cycle.html")
        public String getCarPartialPage() {
            return "admin/cycle";
        }
    }
```

Comment: actually `admin` in url is appending 2 times..

Comment: I think this link might help you to accomplish the error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24388634/ajax-routing-calling-controller-name-twice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the code like below

```
 $routeProvider.when('/cycle', {
   templateUrl: 'cycle.html',
   controller: 'CycleController'
```

});

and in spring controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/cycle.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getCarPartialPage() {
return "admin/cycle";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your getCarPartialPage() method to return "cycle"

Comment: when i remove admin from return it is showing template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers